# integrate facebook to google+

Tags: facebook, google-plus

I hope this question belongs to this site... 
My main social networking is in Facebook but I really wanted to start expanding to other sites. The first thing I did was integrating Twitter and was pretty simple- now whatever I post in FB will automatically be posted in TW. 
Now I want to start working in Google+ but I can't find a way to do it. I want to post in FB and at the same time in G+. I found an app to go the other way around- post in G+ and then share it to FB, but the problem is that is 'shares' in FB and since they are mostly pictures the client wants big pictures in their timeline (the 'sharing' app is way too small). 
So to sum up everything: I need a way to post something in a FB page (http://www.facebook.com/pages/Bajo-Tus-Alas/197298890366783) and share it in a G+ page (https://plus.google.com/108219055045707680914/posts)

Answer (score 0):

You should definetly use some programming lang on the server side.

Comment: you mean on FB servers? like a FB app?

Comment: I don't get it. How can I send the post automatically from FB to my server so I can make the script to share the post in G+?

Comment: You could only check your FB for ex. every 2 minutes for new posts and then post them to G++